How can I test the 'Google Chrome third-party cookie blocking policy
How can I test the 'Google Chrome third-party cookie blocking policy.
I have a hybrid-app and use Webview on both iOS and Android. I use cookies for various purposes.
Does this policy also affect Webview?
If it does, could you tell me how to test it?
If you know ways to test it, please let me know.

Welcome to stackoverflow! Read this post and edit your question.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
